# GCP CloudFunction with a ServerToServer JWT return 403

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I need to call an authenticated cloud function in GCP form another service with the authentication of service account.

This is the snippet used to generate the token :

```
    private String getApiToken() {
        IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential =
                IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
                        .setIdTokenProvider((IdTokenProvider) googleCredentials)
                        .setTargetAudience(appProperties.videoService().videoGeneratorUrl())
                        .setOptions(Arrays.asList(Option.FORMAT_FULL, Option.LICENSES_TRUE))
                        .build();
        try {
            tokenCredential.refreshIfExpired();
            return tokenCredential.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

and `googleCredentials` is a @bean created on the application startup using a Service Account with the environment var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to it

```
    @Bean
    public GoogleCredentials getGoogleCredentials() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
        if (!(credentials instanceof IdTokenProvider)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Credentials are not an instance of IdTokenProvider.");
        }
        return credentials;
    }
```

The service account has (for the moment) "owner" as role in GCP and also forced "role.invoke" on the cloud function.

I also try to make a curl to the CloudFunction with the bearer :

- generated form the application -> 403
- generated with the command `gcloud auth print-identity-token` -> 200

So I think it is a "problem" with the way that I generate the token in java.

Comment: Which Gen of `cloud function` you are using, As per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls) : ***For 1st gen functions, the invoker role is Cloud Functions Invoker (roles/cloudfunctions.invoker). For 2nd gen functions, the invoker role is Cloud Run Invoker (roles/run.invoker)***

Comment: Also can you try to log token to console using `console.log` and share what it is printing? and make sure `appProperties.videoService().videoGeneratorUrl()` method returns the correct audience for the Cloud Function.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @Roopa M comment I find the problem :

**For 1st gen functions, the invoker role is Cloud Functions Invoker (roles/cloudfunctions.invoker).**

---

**For 2nd gen functions, the invoker role is Cloud Run Invoker (roles/run.invoker)**

I set the wrong role to the service account.